# How to mod-rewrite language parameter (e.g. ?lang=en) to fake subdomain (e.g. en.mydomain.com)?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localization, internationalization

It's so hard being a noob. I need someone to help me do this :-(

So basically, I need users to use this url:

> **en**.mydomain.com <- very nice!

instead of using:

> www.mydomain.com/index.php?lang=**en**

I know this is serious .htaccess stuff. Which I may never get my head around without any help. So, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this rule as **your very first rule** in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=en(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
```